# Salvar a opção selecionada do radioButton para consulta futura

Tags: c#, datatable, radiobutton

Gostaria de saber se tem como salvar em um `DataTable` (ou algo do tipo, para ser consultado mais tarde) a informação que um `radioButton` foi clicado. Eu estou fazendo um programa simples para um cliente informar três informações em três `textbox` isso é salvo em uma `DataTable` e é mostrado em uma `DataGrid`. Além disso, gostaria de mostrar qual `radioButton` (se o `radiobutton` de pessoa fisica for selecionado, então o `txt_registro` vai receber um numero de cpf)foi clicado no cadastro que o usuário está visualizando na `DataGrid` (o usuario pode consultar as informações de cadastro depois só clicando em cima da linha da `dataGridView`.

Pensei que talvez isso devesse ser feito dentro da classe, em um método, mas não sei ao certo pois ainda tenho que fazer uma opção para editar o cadastro selecionado (para o usuário poder editar o que ele havia escrito em um cadastro antigo por meio da text box e salvar no mesmo lugar do cadastro antigo.

```
public int con;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Cadastro");


public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dt.Columns.Add("Nome", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Email", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("Registro", Type.GetType("System.String"));

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private void bt_salvar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

    if (con == 1) 
    {
        Fisica dadosfisica = new Fisica(txt_nome.Text, txt_email, txt_registro.Text);
        dr["Registro"] = "CPF: " + dadosfisica.CPF;
        dr["Nome"] = dadosfisica.Nome;
        dr["Endereco"] = dadosfisica.Email;

    }

    if (con == 2)
    {
        Juridica dadosjuridica = new Juridica(txt_nome.Text, txt_email,txt_registro.Text);
        dr["Registro"] = "CNPJ: " + dadosjuridica.CNPJ;
        dr["Nome"] = dadosjuridica.Nome;
        dr["Endereco"] = dadosjuridica.Email;

    }


    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


}>



                 <public class Dados
            {

            private string _nome;
            private string _email;

            //construtor para iniciar os dados privados - recebe parametros
            public Dados(string nome, string email)
            {
             this._nome = nome;

             this._email = email;
            }


            public string Nome
            {
             get
             {
                 return _nome;
             }
             set
             {
                 _nome = value;
             }
            }

            public string Email
            {
             get
             {
                 return _email;
             }
             set
             {
                 _email = value;
             }
            }
            }>

              <//Classe Juridica herdada da classe Dados
            public class Juridica : Dados
            {

                private string nCNPJ;

                public Juridica(string nome, string email, string nCNPJ)
                    : base(nome, email) //chama o construtor da classe base
                {
                    this.nCNPJ = nCNPJ;
                }

                public string CNPJ
                {
                    get{return nCNPJ;}

                    set{nCNPJ = value;}
                }

            }>


              </Classe Fisica herdada da classe Dados
            public class Fisica : Dados
            {
                private string nCPF;

                public Fisica(string nome, string email, string nCPF)
                    : base(nome, email) //chama o construtor da classe base
                {
                    this.nCPF = nCPF;
                }

                public string CPF
                {
                    get{return nCPF;}

                    set{nCPF = value;}
                }

            }>



//Seleção do RadioButton
private void bt_pfisica_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bt_pfisica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_registro.Mask = "000,000,000-00";
        con = 1;
    }
}

private void bt_pjuridica_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bt_pjuridica.Checked)
    {
        txt_registro.Enabled = true;
        txt_registro.Mask = "00,000,000/0000-00";
        con = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode salvar um valor simbólico na DataTable, indicando se ele foi clicado ou não, exemplo:

```
dr["Registro"] = "CPF: " + dadosfisica.CPF;
dr["Nome"] = dadosfisica.Nome;
dr["Endereco"] = dadosfisica.Email;
//Crie uma coluna para salvar o dado pretendido. No caso, usarei o valor '1' para 'clicado' e '0' para não clicado
dr["PessoaFisica"] = dadosfisica.Juridica ? "1" : "0";
```

E então, você pode criar um atributo booleano na sua classe para salvar essa informação:

```
private bool bJuridica;
public bool PessoaJuridica
{
      get{return bJuridica;}

      set{bJuridica = value;}
}
```

, Assim sendo, podes definir o valor no atributo assim:

```
dados.Juridica = bt_pjuridica.Checked;
```

Espero ter entendido corretamente sua dúvida

Comment: Na verdade a ideia não é mostrar em coluna, e sim mostrar o radioButton "checked" quando eu selecionar a linha do cadastro na dataGridView.

Comment: O dr["PessoaJuridica"] = dados.Juridica ? "1" : "0" está dando problemas para encontrar o local de Juridica.

Comment: Sim, você tem que adicionar a coluna na `DataTable` e o atributo na Classe. 

Para definir o radiobutton como "checked", você fazer: `bt_pjuridica.Checked = true;`, caso encontre a condição necessária

Comment: Tem como não adicionar a coluna? Pois eu só quero ver a radioButton selecionada quando eu clicar em uma linha da dataGrid (que tem um cadastro) e o valor do registro já vai estar em uma coluna.

Comment: Se você não precisar guardar a informação em algum lugar, não precisa adicionar a coluna na DataTable.

Comment: Eu só preciso guardar a informação de qual radioButton foi clicado em cada cadastro.

Comment: Então, da maneira que você parece estar desenvolvendo, recomendo guardar qual RadioButton foi clicado na DataTable, juntamente aos outros dados.

Comment: Mas daí eu vou precisar mostrar na coluna, não?

Comment: Você pode colocar a coluna do DataGridView como `.Visible = false;`, assim ela não será visível ao usuário

Comment: Ah, eu não sabia dessa função! Obrigado, vou usar!!

Comment: Por nada :). Vale lembrar que os dados continuarão ali, apenas invisíveis para o usuário

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55080/discussion-between-bellon-and-artur-trapp).